# why i am getting blank list as output in python even after appending item in it?

Tags: python, list, oop

```
  #bll
class cms():
    def __init__(self):
        self.namelist = []
        self.idlist = []
        self.moblist = []
        self.emaillist = []
        self.reslist = []

    def addcustomer(self):
        self.idlist.append(id)
        self.namelist.append(name)
        self.moblist.append(mob)
        self.emaillist.append(email)
        return print("Customer Added")

    def showcustomer(self):
        print(self.idlist, self.namelist, self.moblist, self.emaillist)
#pl
while(1):
    print("Enter Your Choice  Enter 1 to Add, 2 to search, 3 to delete, 4 to Modify, 5 to Display All, 6 to Exit")
    ch = input("Enter your choice")
    conman = cms()
    if ch == '1':
        id = input("ENter your id")
        name = input("Enter Your name")
        mob = input("Enter your mobile no")
        email = input("Enter your email")
        conman.addcustomer()

    elif ch == '2':
        conman.showcustomer()
```

this is my code when I am entering 1 then the customer gets added,but when I call another method to print that appended item it returns blank list
Output:-
    Enter your choice2
    [] [] [] []
Help!! Please.

Comment: Can you edit your question please and make sure all code is in code format rather than in a paragraph?

Comment: okay I will be doing that, just a min.

Answer (score 1):

```
conman = cms()
```

Because this is inside the loop, each time through the loop, this creates a separate, new `cms` with its own lists of data, and makes `conman` be a name for the new value.

```
elif ch == '2':
    conman.showcustomer()
```

This, therefore, displays information from the new `conman`, ignoring everything that was done in the previous iteration of the loop.